# Querying a document in SQL Server 2012 stored as xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, openxml, sql-server-2012

I have been trying to learn Open XML, and I successfully generated a free text 2007 .docx file in Visual Studio c#.  After that I saved the file in the .xml format in Word and then Imported the .xml file into sql server 2012 into a table called XML to a column called xml:   here is the code for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XML](
    [XML_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [XML] [xml] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_XML] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [XML_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Here is the insert I ran

```
INSERT INTO XML(XML)
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'C:\Users\bbt2d\Desktop\Document.xml',
   SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

When I ran a select * the xml file showed up, but when I tried querying some of the data from the paragraphs I wasn't getting anywhere.

Here is a partial snipper of the xml that is stored in sql server:  Was wondering if I went about the process wrong, or how would you query out text from the document.

```
?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
        <Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties" Target="docProps/app.xml" />
        <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties" Target="docProps/core.xml" />
        <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml" />
      </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="256">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
        <Relationship Id="rId8" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/fontTable" Target="fontTable.xml" />
        <Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/settings" Target="settings.xml" />
        <Relationship Id="rId7" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footer" Target="footer1.xml" />
        <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles" Target="styles.xml" />
        <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/numbering" Target="numbering.xml" />
        <Relationship Id="rId6" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/endnotes" Target="endnotes.xml" />
        <Relationship Id="rId5" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footnotes" Target="footnotes.xml" />
        <Relationship Id="rId10" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2007/relationships/stylesWithEffects" Target="stylesWithEffects.xml" />
        <Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/webSettings" Target="webSettings.xml" />
        <Relationship Id="rId9" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/theme" Target="theme/theme1.xml" />
      </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
        <w:body>
          <w:p w:rsidR="00C32D34" w:rsidRDefault="00C32D34">
            <w:pPr>
              <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1" />
              <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
              <w:jc w:val="center" />
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" />
                <w:sz w:val="44" />
                <w:szCs w:val="44" />
              </w:rPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" />
                <w:sz w:val="44" />
                <w:szCs w:val="44" />
              </w:rPr>
              <w:t>School District of Marshfield</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
          <w:p w:rsidR="00C32D34" w:rsidRDefault="00C32D34">
            <w:pPr>
              <w:autoSpaceDE w:val="0" />
              <w:autoSpaceDN w:val="0" />
              <w:adjustRightInd w:val="0" />
              <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria" w:hAnsi="Cambria" w:cs="Cambria" />
                <w:b />
                <w:bCs />
                <w:sz w:val="28" />
                <w:szCs w:val="28" />
              </w:rPr>
            </w:pPr>
          </w:p>
          <w:p w:rsidR="00C32D34" w:rsidRDefault="00DE219B">
            <w:pPr>
              <w:autoSpaceDE w:val="0" />
              <w:autoSpaceDN w:val="0" />
              <w:adjustRightInd w:val="0" />
              <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
              <w:jc w:val="center" />
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria" w:hAnsi="Cambria" w:cs="Cambria" />
                <w:b />
                <w:bCs />
                <w:sz w:val="28" />
                <w:szCs w:val="28" />
              </w:rPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria" w:hAnsi="Cambria" w:cs="Cambria" />
                <w:b />
                <w:bCs />
                <w:sz w:val="28" />
                <w:szCs w:val="28" />
              </w:rPr>
              <w:t>Exploring French</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidR="00C32D34">
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria" w:hAnsi="Cambria" w:cs="Cambria" />
                <w:b />
                <w:bCs />
                <w:sz w:val="28" />
                <w:szCs w:val="28" />
              </w:rPr>
              <w:t xml:space="preserve"> &amp; Spanish</w:t>
            </w:r>
```

Comment: Use the [xml Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx). Can't be more specific than that since have not described the issues you have or the result you want from your XML.

Comment: I would like to return the text 'Exploring French' from the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML you posted isn't complete - assuming your table's XML is complete, you can try something like this (*BTW: as a side-note: I would recommend to **never** use reserved words for your columns; don't call your column **XML** - that's a reserved keyword; use **XmlDoc** or something like that....*)

```
-- define the two XML namespaces we need to use to get to the data in question
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage' as pkg, 
                     'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' as w)
select
    XmlContent.value('(//w:t)[2]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM dbo.YourTable
where ....(some condition here).....
```

The really interesting part is finding out the proper XPath expression to get to your data. Unfortunately, the text you're interested in doesn't seem to be in a specifically marked paragraph, e.g. the `<w:r>` and `<w:rPr>` tags surrounding it don't have any specific attributes you can check for - so all you can do is figure out that it's the second `<w:t>` node in that document that you're interested in, and get to its text that way.

Comment: @ MARC_S Thanks, I modified the query and it retrieved the line of text I need!

Answer (score 1):

i allways suggest to use Xquery when you are dealing with XML datatypes in sql server,Below is the url which gives you clear understanding of Xquery.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mj4qodGsgDA